# Inserting an image into a table cell in HTML

Tags: css, html, html-table, css-tables

I am finding it difficult in inserting an image into my table cell. When I am trying to completely fill the table cell with an image, The size of the table cell is increasing and taking up the whole page.
Here is my code:

```
<div id="bar">
    <table class = "BarTable" style="width:100%;height: 100%">
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 35%">
           <img src="131AZE.jpg" style="height:100%;width: 100%">
        </td>
        <td>Everyone</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and the css part is:

```
#bar {
    height:45%;
    width: 100%;
}

table.BarTable,th,td {
    border:1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Comment: There must be some other css or element that is affecting your solution because it should work https://jsfiddle.net/742gk9fc/

Comment: *I am not getting the expected output* Well tell us what output you are getting and why it is different. Are you using a  firebug or code inspector to check the computed values of the elements?

Comment: When I am inserting an image of higher resolution the size of the table cell is increased and it is taking up the whole webpage.

Comment: Why are you using a table here, what data are you displaying?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `<table>` has a default spacing in cell which we need to clear if not needed.

```
<table class = "BarTable" style="width:100%;height: 100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give the cell with the image the following properties:

```
width: 1%;
white-space: nowrap;
```

This will prevent your image from stretching as it does in the code you provided, and the cell will wrap the image perfectly.

#### Full demo

```css
#bar {
  height: 45%;
  width: 100%;
}

table.BarTable,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.myclass {
  width: 1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar">
  <table class="BarTable" style="width:100%;height: 100%">
    <tr>
      <td class="myclass"><img src="http://rs902.pbsrc.com/albums/ac222/jvac/pattern-background.png~c200"></td>
      <td>Everyone</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a little gap between the image and the border of the cell ¿Is this the problem? only you have set `td` `padding:0`

```css
#bar {
  height:45%;
  width: 100%;
}

table.BarTable,th,td {
  border:1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  line-height: 0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar">
  <table class = "BarTable" style="width:100%;height: 100%">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 35%"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" style="height: 100%;width: 100%"></td>
      <td>Everyone</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you set the CSS styling 'height: 100%' to the  cell and the image's style attribute style="height:100%;width: 100%".

This may be solve the issue.

```
<div id="bar">
  <table class="BarTable" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
   <tr>
     <td style="width: 35%; height: 100%">
       <div style="height: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify- content: center;">
        <img src="131AZE.jpg" style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%">
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>Everyone</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```